# Over-ride as_json in Service Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Very new to this so apologies in advance.

I have some jQuery that accepts json data. My controller is looping through an array of invoices and is formatting the date to my desired style as the date field for example is a timestamp. I realise this is too much like hard work for the controller so I have been pointed towards over-riding `as_json` and shifting the logic to the model.

I'm a big fan of logic in the model but I'm using a service object (not a model) to communicate with an API (where I get my invoices from) I'm not sure how best to re-write the following code to utilise `as_json`:

```
@invoices.each do |invoice|
  invoice.date = Time.at(invoice.date).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
end
render json: @invoices
```

so how can I get my **service object** to do the heavy lifting?

Answer (score 0):

As You like to use service objects (and it's great actually, much better than polluting Your DB model object), I suggest You using [rails serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). Basically You describe an object  which will be Your model representation in JSON. You can check also railscast about those:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers